# XSLT Union of two input xml documents

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, osb

I want to merge two xml documents.

1. $input(Doc A) contains all the possible elements.
2. Main Source(doc B) may or may not contain all the elements
3. Doc B contains repeatable elements.
4. O/P should be a UNION of both documents.

**$input (simplified)**

```
<StudentData>
    <Header>
        <Info></Info>
    </Header>
    <Source>
        <Sinfo></Sinfo>
    </Source>
    <Student>
        <Fname></Fname>
        <Mname></Mname>
        <Lname></Lname>
        <age></age>
        <email></email>
        <subject>                       <!-- Repeatable -->
            <name></name>
            <avg_marks></avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <Hobby>                         <!-- Repeatable -->
            <name></name>
            <desc></desc>
        </Hobby>
    </Student>
</StudentData>
```

**Sample Source(Doc B)**

```
<StudentData>
    <Header>
        <Info>This gives basic information</Info>
    </Header>
    <Student>
        <Fname>Walter</Fname>
        <Lname>White</Lname>
        <age>56</age>
        <email>whwhite@xyz.com</email>
        <subject>
            <name>MATHS</name>
            <avg_marks>80</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <name>CHEMISTRY</name>
            <avg_marks>100</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <name>PHYSICS</name>
            <avg_marks>78</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <Hobby>
            <name>Reading</name>
        </Hobby>
        <Hobby>
            <name>SOCCER</name>
        </Hobby>
    </Student>
</StudentData>
```

**O/p**

```
<StudentData>
    <Header>
        <Info>This gives basic information</Info>
    </Header>
    <Source>                           <!-- Added as empty tags as it is not present in Source -->
        <Sinfo></Sinfo>
    </Source>
    <Student>
        <Fname>Walter</Fname>
        <Mname></Mname>
        <Lname>White</Lname>
        <age>56</age>
        <email>whwhite@xyz.com</email>
        <subject>
            <name>MATHS</name>
            <avg_marks>80</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <name>CHEMISTRY</name>
            <avg_marks>100</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <name>PHYSICS</name>
            <avg_marks>78</avg_marks>
        </subject>
        <Hobby>
            <name>Reading</name>
            <desc></desc>
        </Hobby>
        <Hobby>
            <name>SOCCER</name>
            <desc></desc>
        </Hobby>
    </Student>
</StudentData>
```

> The o/p should contain empty tags if the source(doc B) does not contain that element.

- **Clarification**

I am using Oracle Service Bus. The Source(doc b) will be directly accessible. Doc A can be accessed with $input.

For example, Student Fname can be accessed by:
`$input/StudentData/Student/Fname`

Is there any simple way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to format doc B according to a **template** embodied by doc A. The simple way to do this, IMHO, would be to turn doc A into a proper XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: This is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29727539/4453460); I wrote an answer, and others could add theirs.